# Mocking ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...) is returning null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In my unit test, I've injected a mocked instance of the `ScheduledExecutoryService` class into the class that I'm trying to test so that when the `scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` method is called, it returns a mocked `Future`. For some reason though, it's always returning `null`. Any ideas ?

Application code:

```
Future<?> t = 
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 10, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Test code:

```
@Mock ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
@Mock ScheduledFuture<?> t;

Mockito.doReturn(t).when(scheduledExecutorService).scheduleWithFixedDelay(
any(Runnable.class), anyLong(), anyLong(), any(TimeUnit.class));
```

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate vs scheduleWithFixedDelay ... ?

Answer (score 6):

You are passing Integers (and probably that is the definition of the method parameters) though you are expecting Long values.

Change to:

```
Mockito.doReturn(t).when(scheduledExecutorService).scheduleWithFixedDelay(
any(Runnable.class), anyInt(), anyInt(), any(TimeUnit.class));
```

Comment: I've changed the arguments to long, but still seeing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your application code is using `scheduleAtFixedRate`, but your test code is only mocking method `scheduleWithFixedDelay`.