# Unit test failure on testing a code involving ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, scheduledexecutorservice

To the point of reproducible example, I have the following class

```
public class SampleCaching {

    ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
    @com.google.inject.Inject InterestCache interestCache;
    @Inject MultimediaCache multimediaCache;

    @Inject
    public SampleCaching(InterestCache interestCache, MultimediaCache multimediaCache) {
        this.executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
        this.interestCache = interestCache;
        this.multimediaCache = multimediaCache;
    }

    protected void calculate() {
        interestCache.populateOne();
        interestCache.populateTwo();
        multimediaCache.populateMultimedia();
        log.info("Cache population completed!");
    }

    public void start() {
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::calculate, 
                                0, 20, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // notice initial delay 
    }
}
```

and as it seems the fact is that I wrote a semi-incorrect unit test for this code which reads as :

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class SampleCachingTest {

    @org.mockito.Mock InterestCache interestCache;
    @Mock MultimediaCache multimediaCache;
    @org.mockito.InjectMocks SampleCaching sampleCaching;

    @Test
    public void testInvokingStart() throws Exception {
        sampleCaching.start();
        verify(multimediaCache, times(0)).populateMultimedia();
        verify(interestCache, times(0)).populateOne();
        verify(interestCache, times(0)).populateTwo();
    }
}
```

- I went through [Mocking ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...) is returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786137/mocking-scheduledexecutorservice-schedulewithfixeddelay-is-returning-null) but I don't know for what reasons should I require mocking the return type of `scheduleAtFixedRate` here and anyway the mocks are working fine with me?
- Went through [How to unit test a code snippet running inside executor service, instead waiting on Thread.sleep(time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393697/how-to-unit-test-a-code-snippet-running-inside-executor-service-instead-waiting) to find the most upvoted answer not relating much with a `ScheduledExecutorService` test(at least that's what I am thinking as of now).

*I said, semi-incorrect because this test passes if I increase the initial delay in the actual code to say for an example `1 MINUTE`.*

What really brought me to asking this was that if I change the test to

```
@Test
public void testInvokingStart() throws Exception {
    sampleCaching.start();
    verify(interestCache, times(1)).populateOne();
    verify(interestCache, times(1)).populateTwo();
}
```

it always executes successfully but adding `verify` for multimedia fails the test always on the other hand:

```
verify(multimediaCache, times(1)).populateMultimedia(); // or even to `times(0)`
```

**Is there a reason behind such a behavior(deterministic or deterministic)? What is the correct way to fix this test?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are triggering the method SampleCaching#start yourself, this in turn tells the ScheduledExecutorService to call the calculate method with an initial delay of 0 seconds. This is going to happen in a separate thread. Meanwhile, your test code continues to run and the next thing it does is verify that the populateMultimedia method was not called on your multimediaCache. and then the same for populateOne and populateTwo.
The success of this will depend on the progress made by the calculate method in the other thread that was started. If it has already called the populateMultimedia method then your first verify will fail and so will the others. If on the other hand, it has not progressed that far, the test will succeed but maybe it will fail on populateOne or populateTwo.

You either need to build in a synchronisation mechanism (e.g. java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch) this your calculate method does countDown on at the end and your test code does an await on before verifying or you put a reasonable delay between calling the start method and the verify calls.
The first is intrusive as it changes component that you are testing. You could consider creating a subclass of SimpleCaching that overrides the calculate method but again that is intrusive if your calculate method is private.

Comment: thank you for phrasing the answer, about "*than your first verify will fail and so will the others...*", there is a catch, the test always fails to verify the `populateMultimedia` method, despite me changing the order of the method calls in the actual code or verifies in the test. (I am using IntelliJ to execute these tests, but would it matter on how the methods are being executed during test verification.)..besides that was one of the strange points observed and urged me to put this up as a question.

Comment: Changing the order in the actual code or changing the order of the verifications is not going to change the basic problem with this test. The test fails to ignore the fact that two concurrent threads are executing. One that executes the logic and one that verifies that the logic is being executed and it all depends on the timing of the executing on the threads. Using CountDownLatch will help you.

Comment: Note also that time(0) can be replaced with never() and time(1) can always be left out. So, verify(multimediaCache).populateMultimedia() equals to verify(multimediaCache, times(1)),populateMultimedia()